# MONO_WASM: Assert failed: Expect to have one js-module-threads asset in resources

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am wanting to play with blazor and multithreading.

I added the `<WasmEnableThreads>` and the "Microsoft.NET.WebAssembly.Threading" nuget.
However, I am getting this error:

> MONO_WASM: Assert failed: Expect to have one js-module-threads asset in resources

This is a File | New | Empty Blazor WASM app

Because I am going to be using native files, I have also added `<WasmBuildNative>true</WasmBuildNative>`. I do not have any yet, but this seems to cause the issues.